# In Photoshop, how do you find the name of a layer by clicking within your psd?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

You used to be able to do this by right clicking on the psd, and it would only show you the names of the layers under your cursor.  Now it shoes all layers, even those that are not under your cursor.  I've been away from regular Photoshop usage for a while, so I'm wondering if there is another way to do this..[image: I've added a screenshot. Here I am right clicking on the blue bar in the middle, and for example the "header" folder is not underneath the blue bar.]

I've added a screenshot.  Here I am right clicking on the blue bar in the middle, and for example the "header" folder is not underneath the blue bar.

Comment: Ah, this was fixed after I updated my version.. sorry my initial question was assuming this was a change in functionality, not a bug!

Answer (score 1):

You asked if there is another way to do it. I personally never use right click, because if you have groups it shows a lot of unnecessary layers (it's not the brightest system). What I do is `Ctrl + left click` (no auto select and layer in the drop down menu) and check the layer in the LAYERS panel. If there is something in the way (an effect on top of everything, for example, like a texture or something like that) I block that layer so it won't get in the way.

It's not as clear as having the names in a list, but it's quite effective (the mouse is very precise). I guess it helps if you have good layer names and a good group structure.

Answer (score 1):

It was always the same, but when you have `Layer Groups` **all groups** are displayed and it makes a  mess.

You should just use `Auto Select Layer`.

Comment: Is "Auto Select Layer" a setting or something else? I've moved from Photoshop CS5 to Photoshop CC and I'm almost certain the default behaviour previously was to only show layers under a right click.

Comment: So the "Move tool" toolbar has a selection for "Auto-select" (select on click) and also for what to select - group or layer. Instead of being able to use the right click menu to see just layers under the mouse I can approximate it by setting the drop down to "Layer", then I can ctrl+click and the layer under the mouse is selected.